# I give input 1 to 9.. if the same input occurred 5 times with in 30 sec I want to print that

Tags: c#

```
public class call
{
    DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
    public void check()
    {
        int count=0;
        if(time < time.AddSeconds(30))
        {
            count ++;
            if(count == 5)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(count);
            }
        }
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       int input;
       string sinput;
       call one = new call();
       call two = new call();

       sinput = Console.ReadLine();
       input = int.Parse(sinput);

       do{
            switch(input)
            case 1: one.check();
            break;
            case 2: two.check();
            break;
            default: Console.WriteLine(":::");
            break;
        }while(input > 9)
    }
}
}
```

I am new to programming...

I tried to print the number If it occurred 5 time within 30 sec...
I give input 1 to 9.. if the same input occurred 5 times with in 30 sec I want to print that..

Comment: Please provide compilable code - what is it Java or C# ?

Comment: I don't how to make time constant for on object creation

Comment: @user8223535 why the Java tag then?

Comment: well why tag your question as Java? And I ain't your Bro

Comment: Not similar enough to put both tags on a C# question.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few bugs:

You'll probably want to replace:

```
if(time < time.AddSeconds(30))
```

With something the compares to the current time such as:

```
if(DateTime.Now < time.AddSeconds(30))
```

You are also incrementing count twice in your check method, not sure if that was intentional.

Inside of your do loop your switch body needs to be inside of {} and you probably should be reading a new input each time or doing something else to change the input or your loop will run forever.

You should also always validate user input. In this case if someone enters something other than a number your application will crash form this code:

```
 sinput = Console.ReadLine();
 input = int.Parse(sinput);
```

Instead lookup the int.TryParse method.

Comment: The problem is when I give input 1 again the time change to current time... But I don't want that.. I need same time for that if it not existed  30 sec for same input

Comment: My second code blocked addressed this issue. 'if(DateTime.Now < time.AddSeconds(30))

Answer (score 0):

You create something like a class that logs the data for a certain input value (that is, stores the dates at which they are entered) and a class that binds those. Like, in pseudo-code:

```
class SingleInputLogger {

    List<Date> dates

    void addDate(Date date){
        push date in dates
    }

    unsigned int currentSize(){
        remove all entries from dates which are too old
        return size of dates
    }
}

class InputLogger {

    Array<SingleInputLogger> singleInputLoggers of size 10 (or 9 if only 1..9, but then mind the offset)

    //adds an input and also returns true if the input has a count of more than five
    void addInput(int input){
        singleInputLoggers[input].addDate(currentTime())

    }

    bool checkInput(int input){
        if(singleInputLoggers[input].currentSize() >= 5){
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
```

Then the main routine becomes

```
InputLogger logger

while(get input){
    logger.addInput(input)
    if(logger.checkInput(input)){
        display message "input " + input + " was entered more than five times in 30s"
    }
}
```

(List was used to indicate a linked list in order to be able to efficiently remove front entries, Array was used to indicate a structure of static size for fast access)

Remember to let classes like this do the job for you. Try to use as less functions as possible and rather go with methods.

If someone has better names for those classes (I admit that my names are not that great), feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: I have a confusion on addinput method... The code singleInpuLoggers [input] will show error

Comment: @user8223535 I don't know about your implementation. Post something like a link to cpp.sh with an implementation. Has the array the correct size?